# How to show data from database on notification?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I want to show the data of particular event on notification. Like events title,start time,end time and location.

I have created notification but I have no idea how can I put this data into notification.

I have created `getAllEvents` method in `EventTableHelper` class and retrieving data from it.

This is how I tried to create notification and get the data. How to add this data in notification? How can I customize this notification?

```
public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification myNotification;

    EventTableHelper db;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        db = new EventTableHelper(context);

        List<EventData> testSavings = db.getAllEvents();

        for (EventData ts : testSavings) {
            String log = "from date:" + ts.getFromDate()
                    + " ,to date: " + ts.getToDate()
                    + " ,location: " + ts.getLocation()
                    + " ,title " + ts.getTitle();

            Date date = new Date();
            Date date1 = new Date();
            Log.d("Result: ", log);
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
            try {
                date = df.parse(ts.getFromDate());
                date1 = df.parse(ts.getToDate());
            } catch (ParseException ex) {

            }
            String timeFrom = df2.format(date);
            String startTime = String.valueOf(date);

            String timeTo = df2.format(date1);
            String endTime = String.valueOf(date1);


            String location = ts.getLocation();
            String title = ts.getTitle();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    myIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event")
                    .setContentText("Time")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_48dp)
                    .build();


            Log.i("Notify", "Notification");
            notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to pass it in notification? Can you please guide me through code? @user367618

Comment: tried to load all events data.

Comment: You are getting me wrong. I dont want to send data from notification to activity. I want to show on notification, event's title,start time location etc.

Comment: in for loop just get data and setContentText(your data)

Comment: like this?   .setContentText(title,timeFrom,timeTo,location)

Comment: Its giving error charSequence can not be applied to java.lang.string.

Comment: setContentText(title + timeFrom +timeTo +location)

Comment: great help.. Thank you..